# How to select parent child 'n' th records without recursion in sql?

Tags: sql

I've got the following table.

```
 id |     name     | parent_id 
----+--------------+-----------
  1 | Cat          |          
  2 | Fun          |         1
  3 | LOLCs        |         2
  4 | Anid         |         2
  5 | Cla          |         1
  6 | Rena         |         5

.................................
Up to 'N' th Level
```

I would like to select parent child `nth` records without recursion in SQL.

Could someone provide some guidance on how to do this please?

Comment: Why not recursion? Then do you consider using a `for loop` ?

Comment: If your DBMS doesn't support recursive queries or loops and the number of levels is small there's a classic solution adding another `left join on nextlevel.id = prevlevel.parent_id` for each level.

Comment: If is possible like this type of way ................                                                         SELECT   L0.*  
FROM test L0 JOIN test  L1 ON L0.Parent_Id = L1.Id 
           JOIN test L2 ON L1.Id = L2.Parent_Id   
WHERE L1.id='1' 

UNION  all
 
    SELECT L1.* 
    FROM test L0 JOIN test L1 ON L0.Id = L1.Parent_Id
               JOIN test L2 ON L1.MnuId = L2.ParentId  
               JOIN test L3 ON L2.Parent_Id = L3.Id               
                   WHERE L1.Parent_Id = 1'

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try below query which will concatenate all columns of the table.

```
select COLUMN_NAME +'+ ''|'' '  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

where TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name'
for xml path('')

Comment: This is definitely not related to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you want **'N' th lavel** you have to use recursive query, no other option is available. for reference [Recursive](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).